# How to ignore some unittest test in Pycharm 2017.1?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

There is a button "Show Ignored" in Pycharm test run window. I wonder, how to mark some test as ignored?

[image: Pycharm screenshot]

Comment: Is there a way for pyCharm to hide skittepd test parent groups?
E.g, if a test class contains skipped tests, don't mark the whole class as skipped but rather show it as passed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With just Python `unittest`, you can decorate a test to be skipped with `@skip`. From [unittest — Unit testing framework — Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures) or [unittest — Unit testing framework — Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures):

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @unittest.skip("demonstrating skipping")
    def test_nothing(self):
        self.fail("shouldn't happen")

    @unittest.skipIf(mylib.__version__ < (1, 3),
                     "not supported in this library version")
    def test_format(self):
        # Tests that work for only a certain version of the library.
        pass

    @unittest.skipUnless(sys.platform.startswith("win"), "requires Windows")
    def test_windows_support(self):
        # windows specific testing code
        pass
```

I assume PyCharm is showing you the skipped tests.

Comment: Thanks. I did not even tried to ask google for simple "python skip unittest". I've looked for "ignoring" them. Shame on me.

Comment: Yes, I had to dig a bit to remember it was skip. `@ignore` would probably have been a better choice. :)